# How to convert array to string in yii 1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have following code in my controller in my yii 1application:

```
$recipientRegion=1710;
        $data= Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('user_group_id')
            ->from('user_rights')
            ->where('region_id='.$recipientRegion)
            ->queryAll();
```

`var_dump($data)` returns following result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["user_group_id"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["user_group_id"]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

How can I convert this array result into string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple display one per one:

```
foreach($data as $item) {
   echo $item['user_group_id'];
}
```

Fetch to one string (like @Ripper mentioned):

```
implode(',', array_column($data, 'user_group_id'));
```

It depends on what u want to do with this results. Please describe it so we can provide best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) combined with [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) as

```
imlpode(',', array_column($data, 'user_group_id'));
```

Comment: `implode()` won't work here, cause it array of arrays.